# Unable to add domain to azure web app for a domain coming via Cloudflare proxy

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Why I am unable to add domain to azure web app for a domain coming via Cloudflare proxy even though I have configured the URL to resolve to azurewebsites.net URL via CNAME?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to get through Cloudflare proxy:

1. First you need to turn off proxy in Cloudflare.
2. Configure the URL to point to azurewebsites.net URL in DNS
3. Then add the custom domain.
4. Once the domain is added, enable the proxy again.

Comment: It helped, Thanks for your suggestion Dinesh.